# Non-monotonous DTS in output stream

Tags: ffmpeg, libav, avidemux

Summary of the bug:
Hello,
I've created a network with the mininet simulator on ubuntu 14.04lts. In this network, I want to transfer video between two hosts. I used vlc in Sender host and I used ffmpeg in Receiver host. When I run the ffmpeg, I get a lot of these errors:

```
[avi @ 0x66c1900] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:1; previous: 3497, current: 3480; changing to 3498. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[avi @ 0x66c1900] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:1; previous: 3498, current: 3481; changing to 3499. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[avi @ 0x66c1900] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:1; previous: 3499, current: 3482; changing to 3500. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[avi @ 0x66c1900] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:1; previous: 3500, current: 3483; changing to 3501. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[avi @ 0x66c1900] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:1; previous: 3501, current: 3484; changing to 3502. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
```

Here is the command used:

```
ffmpeg -i rtsp://10.0.0.1:8554/test1.sdp -acodec copy -vcodec copy /home/sana/lab/mrp/test1.avi
```

version of ffmpeg is 4.0_static.

I installed  ffmpeg of https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/
  and install with installation instructions in https://www.johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/faq/

Answer (score 5):

Nevermind, looks like I found the answer.

Try:

```
ffmpeg -use_wallclock_as_timestamps 1 -i rtsp://10.0.0.1:8554/test1.sdp -acodec copy -vcodec copy /home/sana/lab/mrp/test1.avi
```

[FFmpeg source](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html).

You might also need to add `-rtsp_transport tcp` before `-i` if you start noticing errors like `max delay reached. need to consume packet`.

At least this is what fixed the error for me with a rtsp stream.