# ffmpeg Non-monotonous DTS in output stream

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, streaming

When I extract audio from a TS video file, with either VLC, ffmpeg, VSDC Video Editor or Audacity, I get a different length audio file.

In ffmpeg, I get the following warnings:

[adts @ 00fb6fc0] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 17343148, current: 17339279; changing to 17343149. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[adts @ 00fb6fc0] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 17343149, current: 17341199; changing to 17343150. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[adts @ 00fb6fc0] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 17343150, current: 17343119; changing to 17343151. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[adts @ 00fb6fc0] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 17343151, current: 17337359; changing to 17343152. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[adts @ 00fb6fc0] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 17343152, current: 17339279; changing to 17343153. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[adts @ 00fb6fc0] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 17343153, current: 17341199; changing to 17343154. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[adts @ 00fb6fc0] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 17343154, current: 17343119; changing to 17343155. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[adts @ 00fb6fc0] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 17343155, current: 17337359; changing to 17343156. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[adts @ 00fb6fc0] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 17343156, current: 17339279; changing to 17343157. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[adts @ 00fb6fc0] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 17343157, current: 17341199; changing to 17343158. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[adts @ 00fb6fc0] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 17343158, current: 17343119; changing to 17343159. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.

So if I was to replace the audio in the video file with the one I just extracted, audio would be out of sync. Happened with both TS files I got.

When I play the original video file, audio is good, in sync.

The techniques suggested at the following link doesn't work for me:
[Non-monotonous DTS in output stream](https://superuser.com/questions/1326829/non-monotonous-dts-in-output-stream)

How do I fix this?